# How to display the sub-script exactly in the bottom of the sigma?

Tags: displaystyle

- First code:

When I write the following code in TeX:

```
‎\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{5}‎‎a_i
‎\end{align*}
```

then in the output 
the sub-script `i=1` appears exactly in the bottum of the `sigma-symbol`; 
and the super-script `5` appears exactly above the `sigma-symbol`.

---

---

- Second code:

**But** when I write the following code in TeX:

```
note that 
$\sum_{i=1}^{5}‎‎a_i$
is greater than zero
```

in the outcome 
the sub-script `i=1` appears in the right-bottom of the `sigma-symbol`; 
and the super-script `5` appears in the right-above of the `sigma-symbol`.

---

---

> What changes should I apply to the second code;
>   such that the outcome is like the first code?
>   i.e. in the outcome 
>   the sub-script `i=1` appears exactly in the bottum of the `sigma-symbol`; 
>   and the super-script `5` appears exactly above the `sigma-symbol`.

Comment: `$` is inline math designed to fit within the baseline spacing of the paragraph so normally you would use `\[\sum...\]` to get the displaystyle but if you really must, you can use `$\displaystyle\sum...`

Comment: note the first form should be written as `\[\sum_{i=1}^{5}‎‎a_i\]` as it is wrong to use `align*` for single line displays with no alignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also might want to use the `\medop` command from `nccmath` (~ 80 % of `\displaystyle`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. note that $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{5}‎‎a_i $ is greater than zero $ \smash[b]{\medop\sum\limits_{i=1}^{5}}‎‎a_i $. Some more text. Some more text. $ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{5}‎‎a_i $ Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You and some other friends offers too many solutions; but all of them fails when I use the `\oplus` command instead of `\sum` command; exept this one: `$ \smash[b]{\medop\oplus\limits_{i=1}^{5}}‎‎a_i $`. Thank you my dear @Bernard .

Comment: That's normal:  as a maths symbol, `\oplus` has not type `mathop`, but `mathbin`. With such a symbol, you can use `\smash[b]{\overset{5}{\underset{i=1}{\oplus}}}`. The maths operator is `\bigoplus`, but strangely, adding `\medop` make bigger! You can use  `\mathsmaller` from `relsize`, it will have (almost) the size of `\oplus` – with a thicker line.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
note that 
$\sum_{i=1}^{5}\limits ‎‎a_i$
is greater than zero
```

preserving small sum sign, but it also may change the vertical spacing.